# How to add form controls dynamically for a checkbox?

Tags: angular

I know I'm doing something wrong that's obvious and excuse my ignorance. basically I want to dynamically create a formControl for my checkbox array. what I intend is to validate that a checkbox is selected at least. how can I do it?

```
this.validationForm = fb.group({
  text:[null, [Validators.required]]
  // I dont know how to create a form control dynamic,that's why I have not put it here
});


aData=[
 {"name":"goku", "select":true},
 {"name":"vegeta", "select":false},
 {"name":"krillin",  "select":true}        
]


<form [formGroup]="validationForm" >
  <input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let item of aData" [formControlName]="item.select">{{item.name}}
  <input type="text" formControlName="text">  
</form>

<button (click)="fn_submit(validationForm)">Validate form</button>
```

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7iywjj?file=src/app/app.component.html

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You were looping through the wrong object in your template. You have to use the `group` you created in the form initialization.

You can created your dynamic group of checkboxes like this:

```js
const formControls = this.aData.map(control => new FormControl(false));

this.validationForm = this.fb.group({
   checkboxes: new FormArray(formControls),
   text: new FormControl()
});
```

Here is your working forked live code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztab6u?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks genious! thanks for answering. Do you know how I can validate that you have at least one option selected? and I know that you define "checkboxes: new FormArray (formControls)" inside the constructor, could it be added dynamically from the outside?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz. You juste have to pass the initial value you want to the FormControl constructor: `const formControls = this.aData.map(control => new FormControl(control.select))` in your case.

Comment: You are very kind, I do not want to bother you anymore but how can I validate my form to validate that at least one checkbox is selected?

Comment: In your save function, just implement a loop through your checkboxes form controls to check if at least one is selected